# Eclipse INI file option

Tags: eclipse

I found one strange setting in eclipse.ini file:-
-DprodMode=production

Does any body know what this setting is used for?

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard Eclipse option, so it must be something specific to your configuration/distribution. Considering that it is standard Java system property, anybody might be using it.

If you are basing your Eclipse installation on vanilla Eclipse and you are not using some already customized installation, you can observe which adds this option in eclipse.ini by checking the file after each installation.

Vanilla Eclipse packages don't have this property (or at least Eclipse Classic, Eclipse for Java Developers and Eclipse for Plug-in Developers).